# How to swich off "Text selected" panel in Android

Tags: android, text, selection, panel

How to swich off "Text selected" panel in Android app

[image]

Comment: I don't know if you can turn it off. When the user presses and holds on a lot of text, this option is enabled by the system.

Comment: Is it possible to turn off the selected text in Android App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switch off long click:

```
webView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener(){         
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {             
        return true;
    }
});
```

That works for me.